# Django 1.8 import issue

Tags: django, python-2.7

This is the first time I need to run my app deeper in the directory structure, I have obviously messed up my app structure while setting this up and can't get it right anymore. Could somebody help me out here?

In my start.sh file I define following env vars:

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:'/home/ubuntu/workspace/skw/3rd_apps/'
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:'/home/ubuntu/workspace/skw/cskw/'
```

And my dir structure looks like this:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/skw/start.sh (also manage.py and gulpfile)
/home/ubuntu/workspace/skw/3rd_apps/ (django is here)
/home/ubuntu/workspace/skw/cskw/ (contains __init__.py)
/home/ubuntu/workspace/skw/cskw/apps/ (contains __init__.py)
/home/ubuntu/workspace/skw/cskw/core_app/ (settings.py is here and __init__.py)
```

I cycle between two errors here:
1. When trying to setup a custom signup form:

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'core_app.forms.SignupForm'
```

The form is in place but i get this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Module "core_app.forms" does 
not define a "SignupForm" class
```

2. And if I fix this I can not import anything from apps, it expects them to be in core_app and does not see the app module at the same level as core_app.

manage.py points to "core_app.settings", so do the variables in settings.py.

Comment: For 2., you haven't said what you do to fix the error, or what the new errors are. You haven't shown where `forms.py` is either. Your `/home/ubuntu/workspace/skw/cskw/` directory shouldn't need an `__init__.py`.

Comment: Note that Django 1.8 is end of life and does not receive security updates any more.

Comment: @Alasdair: I am aware that django 1.8. is old I choose it because of some compatibility issues while the whole transition to P3 is finished. As for 1) the difference is caused either by removing some of the init files (the one in cskw) or changing import names from cskw.core_app to core_app .. and so on. I am obivously lost in this now ...

Comment: There isn't enough information to give you a specific solution. If you have added `/home/ubuntu/workspace/skw/cskw/` to the Python path, then that directory should not contain an `__init__.py`, and your imports should not start with `cskw` (e.g. use `core_app` or `apps`, not `cskw.core_app` or `cskw.apps`).